# ui-grid sort data after filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

**I have this model containing labels in the user selected language.**

```
"status": [{
        "id": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "label": "In progress"
    }, {
        "id": "KO",
        "label": "Everything is KO"
    }, {
        "id": "OK",
        "label": "Everything is OK"
    }]
```

**Data from server:**

```
myService.data =[{
status:"OK",
history:"History 2"
},{
status:"IN_PROGRESS",
history:"History 3"
},{
status:"KO",
history:"History 4"
}
]
```

**In my controller I have the following:**

```
vm.myList = {
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
            enableRowSelection: false,
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            multiSelect: false,
            paginationPageSizes: [6],
            paginationPageSize: 6,
            useExternalSorting: false,
            paginationTemplate: "views/templates/grid-custom-pager.html",
            columnDefs: [{
                    displayName: "recording.status",
                    field: 'status',
                    headerCellFilter: 'translate',
                    cellFilter: 'translate',
                    sortCellFiltered: true,
                    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" translate-field="status" translate-value="COL_FIELD"></div>'
                },
                {
                    displayName: "recording.history",
                    field: 'history',
                    headerCellFilter: 'translate'
}],
data: myService.data}
```

When I press the header cell for sorting, the sort is made by the **field** value, not by the **displayed** value. Is there any way of sorting the column after the filtering is done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating your own sorting algorithm? See the wiki page of the project [Sorting in Ui-Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Sorting)